# Python pandas using an If..elif..else with multiple or

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm looking to use something simialr to .isin instead of multiple or's in this code:

```
def func(row):
    if row['Office'] == 'USA' or row['Office'] == 'UK' or row['Office'] == 'Aus' or row['Office'] == 'Can':   
        return 1        
    else:
        return 2
    
office_data['Area'] = office_data.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: When posting questions with code, always please tell us what language the code is written it. You do that with a specific language tag. For this time I've added the Python language tag, as the code looks like Python, but in the future please make sure you add all *relevant* tags. And are you using Pandas? Then you should [edit] your question to add the `pandas` tag as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using **Python +3.10**, you can use the `match - case` in replace of `IF` statements:

```
def func(row):
  match row['Office']:
    case 'USA':
      return 1

    case 'UK':
      return 1

    case 'Aus':
      return 1

    case 'Can':
      return 1

    case _:
      return 0
```

For your case, I would recommend using a dictionary with the possible candidates, like this:

```
def func(row):
  valid_options = ['USA', 'UK', 'Aus', 'Can']
  if row['Office'] in valid_options: return 1
  return 0
```

Comment: As suggested the second solution is exactly what i was after, Thanks